# How to shape the active list in the navigation menu like the attached image?

Tags: html, css

I have this html code:

```
<ul class="nav">                    
   <li id="home" class="active""><a href="/">Home</a></li>        
   <li id=""><a href=""></li>
</ul>
```

I want to shape the "active" class to the attached active one in the image attached.

[the desired shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiDjt.png)

I tried:

```
.active{
  border-radius:60%;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

and more other css properties but I can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `css` style to your a link element, setting it as display block-level element and also set your `border-radius` a fixed pixel.

```css
ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
.active a{
          display: block;
          border-radius:15px;
          padding: 10px;
          background: #ccc;
}
.active a:hover{
          background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
   <ul class="nav">                    
         <li id=""><a href="">Link 01</a></li>
         <li id=""><a href="">Link 02</a></li>
         <li id=""><a href="">Link 03</a></li>
      <li id="home" class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>        
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `border-radius` value in *pixels* which is at least equal to half of the height (including the padding):

```css
li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}
.active{
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 3px 15px 0px;
  background: #fb9;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">                    
   <li id="home" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>        
   <li id="x"><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me , but the padding should be 0px 15px

Comment: You can set the padding any way you want, but the padding in your image certainly isn't 0/15 (note the little change I made). Actually the radius just needs to be *at least*  half of the height, so it's not that critical.

Answer (score 0):

you must write styles for your preference on *active* class.

```
.active{
background:xx;
border-radius:xx;
padding:xx;
}
```

The color of the active class is like blue in the attached image. so the text color should be black or any dark colors. so that the customers can view it easily.Its a good user experience.